# Evolutionary Algorithm framework in Java

Tags: java, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I have an multi-objective optimization problem which I would like to solve, preferably in Java using evolutionary algorithms.

I use a parametric finite element model with a couple of real or integer input values x1...xn describing for example the geometry of the model. Each parameter can have values in a certain interval, e.g. `x1 \in [2,10]`, `x2 \in [1,4]`, ...

My goal is to find the optimum solution for one or more given criteria which I calculate within the finite element model. So the values of the objective function are calculated by the model.

I basically need a framework where I can define optimization parameters with certain intervals (x1...xn). The framework should build an initial population with starting values for x1...xn for each individual. With those values I create my model for each individual, perform my calculations and give back the values of the target funtion. Than the framework does its job and creates a new offspring population.

Is there an evolutionary algorithm framework in Java that can do that?

I had a quick look at [TinyGP](http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/staff/rpoli/TinyGP/), [Jenetics](http://jenetics.io/) and [JGAP](http://jgap.sourceforge.net). But these focus on Genetic Programming and Symbolic Regression problems. Or did I miss something fundamental?

Comment: That is library what you are describing, not framework. Regardless the question is off topic.

Comment: @John Ok, so where should I ask this question than?

Comment: Jenetics supports multi-objective optimization, check out section 4.1.7 in the [user guide](http://jenetics.io/manual/manual-5.0.0.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [watchmaker api](http://watchmaker.uncommons.org/)